# Unity 5 - Adding a Pre-made Countdown Timer C# Script to the Game Scene as a Text UI Element

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello I am currently Devolping a Game Scene and require a countdown timer to appear in the top left corner of the screen as a text UI element. I already have a script prepared and simply need to add the component to the game scene.

I have created a text object (called CountdownTimer) in the canvas section of my hierarchy. Created a blank game object, added the script as a component and have added the relevent text object where asked for

Alas this has not worked and I'm unsure why but I believe it to be the way the text object is set up or the way in which I have called upon my script

Here's the relevent C# code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;

public class CountdownTimer : MonoBehaviour {

public int maxCountDownTimeLeftInSecond = 15;
public Text Text_Countdown_Timer = null;

public static double secondsLeft = 0.0;

DateTime GameStartDateTime;

void Start ()
{
    GameStartDateTime = DateTime.Now;
}

void FixedUpdate ()
{
    TimeSpan currentTimeLeft = DateTime.Now - GameStartDateTime;
    secondsLeft = maxCountDownTimeLeftInSecond -         
    currentTimeLeft.TotalSeconds;

    if (secondsLeft > 0) 
    {
        Text_Countdown_Timer.text = "Time Left: " + string.Format (" 
        {0:0.00s", secondsLeft);
    } else {
        Text_Countdown_Timer.text = "Time Left: 0.00s";
    }
}
}
```

I appologise if this is a simple question and I'm missing something very obvious but any help is much appriciated. Thank you

Comment: Your code, as you've posted it, should not even compile. https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxxWp.png

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying the code isn't working or the text object doesn't show up in your game? If it is the latter, this could have to do with the layer. If it is at the same depth as the background, it won't show up. Try bringing it up a bit.

Comment: The text object does not show up in my game. The script is coppied from the one my university has provided and I believe the error is in unity itself and the way I have the game scene set up

Comment: Ok, yeah, I would say it's possible that the game object is at the same depth as the background. Try setting the background to a -5 depth, so that way everything else will be slightly higher. This is assuming you are working on a 2D game?

Comment: No unfortunately this is a 3d scene with a 3rd person character. Sorry I should have specified